# How to make translucent to UIView in iOS7

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uinavigationbar

In navigation bar, i can make translucent navigation bar style. But i can not make in UIView like that. 
How can I make translucent style in UIView?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A hack would be using a UIToolBar just like you would use a normal UIView, since in iOS 7 it does the blur for you, better than any other attempts of a blur effect custom UIView. (This will only work in iOS7, for iOS 6 just add a normal alpha)

```
 UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolBar alloc] init];
 [toolBar setFrame:kYourFrame];
 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
      [toolBar setAlpha:0.9];
 }
 [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Answer (score 14):

#### Solution in Swift, compatible with Interface Builder

Create a file named BlurView.swift in your Xcode project :

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class BlurView : UIView {
    // Use the following property to set the tintColor. Set it to nil to reset.
    @IBInspectable var blurTintColor: UIColor! {
        set {
            toolbar.barTintColor = blurTintColor
        }
        get {
            return toolbar.barTintColor
        }
    }
    lazy var toolbar:UIToolbar = {
        // If we don't clip to bounds the toolbar draws a thin shadow on top
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: self.bounds)
        toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.insertSubview(toolbar, atIndex: 0)
        let views = ["toolbar": toolbar]
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[toolbar]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[toolbar]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        
        return toolbar
    }()
}
```

Then you can use it programmatically or directly in IB.

---

#### Programmatically

Create and use a `BlurView` the same way you use any `UIVIew`.

```
var myView:BlurView // ...

// Activate the translucent effect by setting `blurTintColor`
myView.blurTintColor = UIColor.redColor() // Or any color
// If you need to desactivate the effect later
// myView.blurTintColor = nil
```

##With Interface Builder
Add a UIView and set its custom view to `BlurView` :
[image]
Then you can set the Blur Tint Color to activate the translucent effect :
[image]
Note: the blur will only appear at runtime.

##Result

[image: BlurView]

*Inspired by https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur*

Comment: There seems to be no need for the parent view. Simply use a UIToolbar (or subclass UIToolbar) and assign `ClipToBounds = true` to it. But thanks for this solution, it was the key!

Comment: Yes, it should be doable with a UIToolbar subclass, I don't remember why I did it like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a blur layer from UIToolBar to the view which you want it to be translucent.

Look at this open source project:https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this one: https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView
It provides native iOS 7+ blur (translucent) effect